# "Column reference is ambiguous" GraphQL, PostgreSQL & TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

If I run below query in pgAdmin it works perfectly fine:

```
UPDATE customer SET token = array_append(token, '123132');
```

Now, if I run this with TypeOrm I get "column reference "token" is ambiguous"

```
 const result = await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(Customer)
    .values([
      {
        orgId: records.orgId,
        token: [records.token],
      },
    ])
    .onConflict(
      `("orgId") DO UPDATE SET token = array_append(token, '123132')`
    )
    .returning("*")
    .execute();
```

To my eyes, the query is exactly the same. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are constructing is `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`, which is quite different from `UPDATE`. The ambiguity arises because it is not clear if you are speaking about the original column value or the new value supolied by the `INSERT`.

Qualify the column appropriately:

```
SET token = array_append(customer.token, '123132')
```

The new value from the `INSERT` would be qualified with `excluded`.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!